# Power Shell updating property

Tags: powershell

I play around with Power Shell... And I have a newbie question to navigate with ie.
Have this Code:

```
# IE window
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true

function waitforpageload {
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; }
}

# navigate to the first page
$ie.Navigate("http://ss64.com/bash/")
waitforpageload
$ie.Document.Url # return http://ss64.com/bash/
# navigate to the second page
$ie.Navigate("http://ss64.com/ps/")
waitforpageload
$ie.Document.Url # return also http://ss64.com/bash/
```

and I'm wondering why $ie.Document.Url in both times return http://ss64.com/bash/
should is it possible to get http://ss64.com/ps/ in the second call?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I cut/paste your code into PowerShell, and the second `$ie.Document.Url` returns `http://ss64.com/ps/`. So I don't know what's wrong when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get the current location using

> $ie.LocationURL

To get a list of all methods and properties available, use `$ie | gm`